# How to ask Siri to do timezone conversion?

Tags: siri

For example, "What's 9PM Eastern Standard Time in Central Time?"

Answer (score 1):

I can’t think of a way to get this to work since most searches like this go to the iPhone as web results.

Have you tried asking what time it is in Chicago? You would need to know a city in the destination time zone and do math in the best case or ask two questions and do a little more math if you happened to be in CET with Siri.